# Time hierarchy in SSAS (dyslexia)

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

Time dimension have hierarchies:

- Year – month – date
- Year – week – date
- Year - month

I query them so:

```
LASTPERIODS( -12, StrToMember("[Time].[Year -  Week -  Date].[Week].&[" + Format(now(), "yyyy-MM-" + "01T00:00:00") + "]"))
```

returns null

```
LASTPERIODS( -12, StrToMember("[Time].[Year - Month].[Month].&[" + Format(now(), "yyyy-MM-" + "01T00:00:00") + "]"))
```

returns future 12 months

If i query like this:

```
select non empty([Time].[Year -  Week -  Date].[Week].members) on 0
```

it will give me the week members..

Am I missing some parameter?

Answer (score 0):

It's really down to how your keys are made. By using the &, you're saying to use the underlying key, not the name.

In your first example, you're asking for weeks that have an underlying key in the format of "yyyy-MM-01T00:00:00", which seems more like a start-of-month than a start of week.

When you run your second query, does it give you elements like the query you're trying to write?

Comment: LASTPERIODS( -12, StrToMember("[Time].[Year -  Week -  Date].[Week].&[" + Format(now(), "yyyy-MM-dd" + "T00:00:00") + "]")) , cannot find the week member UNLESS the now()-date is beginning of the week. 

Second query works fine as months always start at date 01.

Comment: @user1800552 Exactly, you're trying to use a week member that doesn't exist - now() is only the start of the week 1 day out of 7. So you could either take now() and work out where the start of the week is, or take the current day by using now() and work out where you would be in the week hierarchy by using the MDX navigation/set functions.